# Combine jpeg image with figure

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to combine a jpg image with a simple subplot of a continuous line between -1 to 1
but I havent manage it yet. The problem is that jpg images are being loaded with 3 dimensions(RGB) and a figure can only accept arrays with two dimensions.

Any ideas??

Thanx in advance

Until now I have managed this by searching online:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
print fig,axes
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(np.random.random(100))

image=im.imread('image.jpg')
plot = plt.imshow(image)

plt.text(image.shape[1]/2, 10, "Does this refer to a ?", horizontalalignment = "center")

axes[1].autoscale(False))



plt.show()
```

Comment: "*a figure can only accept arrays with two dimensions*" - Can you be more precise? What API call can only accept arrays of two dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Does this do what you want?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as im

fig, (chart, picture) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

# First, the chart
chart.plot(np.random.random(100))

# Second, an image
image=im.imread('image.jpg')
picture.imshow(image)
picture.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]